# How do I activate the north (second?) generator on the Sandship?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I've already activated the south generator on B1.  I can see the room the north generator is in, but its hallway door is blocked.

The room directly to its east is unlocked, but the door between the two is blocked with electric beams.  The room has bars between them, but I can't see anything to shoot in the generator room.

The east door is blocked if I turn off the time shift stone, so I can't just turn it off, run in, and pull the switch to unblock the hallway door.

How do I get to the north generator to activate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Oops, It looks like I got the rooms mixed up.</sup>

So the generator you're talking about is the one that is next to the room where you had to push a block on a switch to keep the windows open.  These windows you could climb up out of.  The one on the left has a ladder going down and the one on the right should give you access to the dinghy.

To get to the generator, you need to shift time to the present to disable those beams.  However, you needed to be in the past to get to the room in the first place.  You need to shift back to the present from there.  How do you do it?

Well you need to lower the dinghy so you can reach the deck and hit the crystal.  From that room, it would be easier to just climb out the window with the ladder, go down and and look toward the other window and up at the deck.  You should see the dinghy there with a target to hit.  Hitting it will lower/raise it.

After you had lowered it, you can return and climb onto it and hit the target again to raise you to the deck.  From there, shoot the time crystal to shift to the present.  Then you could return to that room using the dinghy and to the generator.  Now you need to shift back to the past again so you can activate the generator.  Fortunately there's a grate above with a clear view to the time crystal.  Shoot it so you can shift to the past and finally activate the generator.

---

To get to the second generator (the one in the south), start off from the first generator.

You'll notice that the room across the hall on the left has a fan in there.  If you are in the past (everything is colorful and operational), the fan should be spinning.  Inside that room, you should see a blue switch that you'd have to shoot at.  You cannot shoot through the fan when it's off so you need to go to the present (where everything is dull and not working) and shoot it then.  That should open the door to enter the room (IIRC).

In the room there should be a switch on your left and bars on the right looking into the next room with a box sitting on a platform.  The switch opens a hatch that covers a target that you have to shoot at however you don't have a direct line of sight to it since the box is in the way.  You'll need to move the box over so you have access to the fan behind it.  You need to open that hatch and shoot at the target.  With the box out of the way (and the fan off), you should be able to do so.  It should open the gate leading to that room.

Now you have access to the generator so you just have to go back into the past where it's operational and turn it on.  You can access the crystal back in the room with the previous generator.

Comment: These are the directions to activate the south generator.  The one I need to activate is the north generator (assuming up = north on the map).  In fact, you can't reach the north generator without activating the south generator first because the room with the south generator has the switch to unblock the door with the windows in it (the "east room" mentioned above).

Comment: Did I just explain how to get to the other generator?  The south one?  Sorry, I don't know how the map was oriented so it wasn't clear to me which one you were talking about.  I figured the one by the windows would be the first one you saw.

Comment: I had missed that the dinghy had a switch to lower it.  Whoops.

Comment: @badp: Could you make them bold instead of nothing?  I just want to make sure they stand out.  I'd do it myself but I hit the editing limit for today.

Comment: @Jeff I don't quite think you need to highlight _all_ the things :)

Comment: @badp: I'm just trying to make sure that key items are the ones standing out.  Though now that I look back at this, I probably wouldn't have made those highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the time crystal, then go back down and shoot through the fan at a gem.  Then the door will open, then go turn the time crystal on again. Go back to that room and move the box on top of all the other boxes. Shoot through there and ta-da!